# Doctrine: retrieving an ordered single entity from a one to many relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

Suppose the following structure database structure - whereby a category has many articles, and an article has many comments:

```
Category:
- id

Article:
- id
- category_id

Comment:
- id
- created_at
- article_id
```

Using Doctrine, what is the best/standard way to:

1. Fetch 10 *Articles* and eager load the most recent *Comment* for each article
2. Fetch 10 *Categories* and eager load the most recent *Comment* in each category

By comparison in Laravel, I could've set up a relation on the Category entity to have one Comment through the Article, and ordered it by the created date. However, I do not know how to achieve this via Doctrine or DQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no "standard way" for it with eager load. I mean no way to setup it with some config/annotations.

I'd do it in following way:

- Create CommentRepository class
- Create `getMostRecentCommentsForCategories(array $categories)` and `getMostRecentCommentsForArticles(array $articles)` methods in it
- They can return arrays of comments grouped by category/article ID

Answer (score 1):

For ordering you can use the `@OrderBy` annotation, e.g.

```
   /**
     * @var RiskMitigation[]|ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\RiskMitigation", mappedBy="risk")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"effectiveDate" : "ASC"})
     */
    private $mitigations;
```

However, your plan to eagerly load only the 10 latest is impossible using annotations.